# monitor stored procedures/queries calls on gcloud MySQL server

Tags: google-app-engine, gcloud, history

Could anyone help me with this? I am using Workbench tool to administer a MySQL server (application engine) on a Google Cloud SQL instance. How can I see the history of all queries/stored procedures calls that have been made to this instance?

I 've searched the web and the tutorial of gcloud, but most of them refer to specific linux commands that i should run on the specific SQL instance, but the problem here is that I haven't access (browsing) to the file system of this MySQL instance, because it's an Application Engine.

So, is there any way to see the queries / stored procedures history:
a) either directly from MySQL instance app engine,
b) or from Google Cloud Console or Workbench?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hello, Just to be sure... do you mean that you are running a SQL inside [App Engnie](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard)?

Comment: Yes, exactly this.